# Booting to OSX on Secondary Drive Disables User Input

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dual-boot

I have two A1297 17" MBPs. The first is a 2010 and the second is a 2011.

Encountering graphics card issues with the 2011, but needed to use both computers until I take the time to sit down and switch to the onboard card.  To tide me over I put the 2011 SSD into the CD drive bay of the 2010, and believed I'd just take the advantage of dual booting to the drive I need to use at any given time.  Here's where the problem starts.

**Power + Option** shows both drives. Awesome:

a) If I choose the **default 2010 SSD**, we're all good. Everything works as normal. I can even access files on the 2011 SSD if and when required, through Finder.

b) If I choose the **2011 SSD**, it boots up and after auth, takes me to the desktop.  But, *I can't type anything, or click anything*, even though the trackpad will allow me to move the cursor.

What gives?

Comment: Boot in Safe mode (hold Shift while booting)  does that change anything?

Comment: How do you boot in safe mode after you dual boot (OPTION)?

Comment: When you have your boot partition selected, hold the shift key.